# T-SQL Query using WHERE clause with CONVERT or CAST

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble with a specific T-SQL Query generated in code.

Below is the code, the first `DECLARE` block is sent from code, so those values will change.

The XML business has to do with turning the CSV `NVARCHAR` into a temporary table.

```
-- DECLARE BLOCK IS SENT BY CODE FROM DIALOG BOX
DECLARE @IdString NVARCHAR(MAX) ='F6LC1'
DECLARE @pm_StartDate DATETIME ='20180201'
-- END DECLARE BLOCK

DECLARE @listOfIds table(entityId nvarchar(50));

DECLARE @x XML 

SELECT @x = CAST('<A>'+ REPLACE(REPLACE(@IdString,' ',''),',','</A><A>')+ '</A>' AS XML)

INSERT INTO @listOfIds
SELECT t.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS inVal
FROM @x.nodes('/A') AS x(t)

DECLARE @pm_StartDateTrim NVARCHAR(MAX) = LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@pm_StartDate,112),6)
DECLARE @intStartDate INT = CAST(@pm_StartDateTrim AS INT)

SELECT @pm_StartDate
SELECT @pm_StartDateTrim
SELECT @intStartDate

SELECT   gl.[ACCTNUM]
        ,acc.[ACCTNAME]
        ,gl.[ENTITYID]
        ,CONVERT(INT,gl.[PERIOD]) AS periodConverted
        ,gl.[ACTIVITY]
        ,bldg.[BLDGNAME]
        ,bldg.[BLDGGLA]
        ,gl.[BALFOR]
FROM [dbo].[GLSUM] AS gl
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[BLDG] AS bldg ON gl.[ENTITYID] = bldg.[BLDGID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[GACC] AS acc ON gl.[ACCTNUM] = acc.[ACCTNUM]
WHERE gl.ENTITYID IN (SELECT entityId FROM @listOfIds)
        AND gl.BASIS = 'A'
        AND gl.ACTIVITY != 0
        AND gl.PERIOD NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
        AND CONVERT(INT,gl.[PERIOD]) >= @intStartDate
ORDER BY gl.PERIOD ASC
```

I'm TRYING To only include those records that have a `PERIOD` which is greater-than or equal-to the provided `StartDate`.

The data in the DB for `PERIOD` is just `YYYYMM`, so like `201502`.

The data provided for the `StartDate` is `DATETIME`, so I'm converting to `YYYYMM` to do the comparison.

I'm TRYING to make them both `INT` so I can compare using `<` or `>` or `=` etc.

So if I leave in the 2nd to last row `AND CONVERT(INT,gl.[PERIOD]) >= @intStartDate` then i get `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'R2W274' to data type int.`

The problem is that there is no value like that in my data.

When I comment out that line, I get data and `R2W274` is not anywhere to be found in any field of any record.

I believe the `R2W274` value is actually in the `gl.ENTITYID` field but not in any of my records, just generally in the DB.

So, I'm not sure why this query is even attempting to convert the `gl.ENTITYID` in the first place.

Any help?

**UPDATE:**

I added the recommended addition to the `WHERE` clause above. I still get the same error.

Comment: So to make it clear, when you do --> select * from [dbo].[GLSUM] where [Period] = 'R2W274'  -- there is no result returning in the output right?

Comment: ah... u are correct. looks like they have an incorrect entry in the DB. there are a couple with these values. hmmm... how can i filter these erroneous values out instead of throwing an error (try/catch maybe?)

Comment: You've assumed that the logic in a `where` clause executes left-to-right with short circuiting, i.e. checking the characters in `PERIOD` prior to applying `CONVERT` and skipping the row if there are problem characters detected. Sadly, but there is no such guarantee. In modern versions of SQL Server [`Try_Convert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) can be used to survive _bad_ data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure there is no data returning from:

```
select * from [dbo].[GLSUM] where [Period] = 'R2W274'
```

Adding a try/catch block like that will help:

```
BEGIN TRY  
    -- Generate divide-by-zero error.  
    your select query comes here.  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    -- Execute error retrieval routine.  
    print 'error';
END CATCH;
```

Try/catch block reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql

What I would do is to eliminate such data inside where clause:

```
WHERE gl.ENTITYID IN (SELECT entityId FROM @listOfIds)
        AND gl.BASIS = 'A'
        AND gl.ACTIVITY != 0
        AND gl.[PERIOD] not like '%[^0-9]%'
        AND CONVERT(INT,gl.[PERIOD]) >= @intStartDate
```

**Edit:** I was expecting the change in where clause would fix it, surprised why it is not working. Please make sure you added the filter before the one including the conversion. Maybe it would be safer to use a temptable like:

```
select * 
into #temp_glsum
from [dbo].[GLSUM] gl
WHERE gl.[PERIOD] not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

and use `#temp_glsum` in your main query instead of `[dbo].[GLSUM]`

Comment: You probably meant to write `AND gl.[PERIOD] NOT like '%[^0-9]%'`

Comment: I agree with this approach, would be better to remove these in the where clause, unless you want to build in a try catch for transaction committal etc.

Comment: i updated the `WHERE` clause as above and i still get the exact same error. as if it is attempting to run the `WHERE` on all rows regardless, not sequentially filtering as we go through the `AND` statements.

Comment: yes - temp table was the answer. i will add full new query above for reference.

Comment: You can also use a nested subquery, or a CTE